# mongo-cxx-client linux unwanted "v_noabi" subdirectory

Tags: linux, mongodb, g++, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

after installing the mongo-cxx-driver from source as described on their homepage (http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/linux/)
on my debian machine, the installation directory results in:

"/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx"

The same for bsoncxx. I tried all the suggested parameters on their advanced configuration site (http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/advanced/) to prevent the creation of v_noabi subdirectory without success.

The problem with this directory is that it will make me unable to include the sourcefiles into my c++ project. For instance, when including "mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx/foo.h", it will complain that foo.h can't include a dependency, because the include path inside the foo.h is just "mongocxx/bar.h" without the "v_noabi" directory.

mongocxx-version is 3.6
linux kernel is 5.10.0
os is kali linux release 2021.1

Anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: you already tried adding that v_noabi  to your include path `-I /whever/you/installed/to/mongocxx/v_noabi` ?  and including these files like normal `#include "mongocxx/foo.h`

Comment: oh my gosh, simple as that. How didn't I think about this on my own. :'D thank u very much!

Comment: @Quirynn Well, actually I am having the same issue and it still does unpleasant things to the code. However, the docs suggest that v_noabi thing must be there: http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/ just look at the tut and the way they declare all of those in the include. Nonetheless, there are still some internal problems